# Как хранить разные характеристики для определённых товаров?

Tags: интернет-магазин

Нужно для товаров добавить характеристики в БД, типа оперативной памяти для телефонов или размеров для сумок.

Возник вопрос: как хранить разные характеристики для определённых товаров?
То есть, у сумок такие характеристики: ширина, длина. У телефонов оперативная память и диагональ. Как хранить набор характеристик для каждой категории? В отдельной таблице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отдельном многострочном поле. Не могу сказать как правильно называется в SQL, а в Access зовется тип поля "memo"

Comment: Можно подробнее, никогда не работал с таким

Comment: Теперь, оказывается, называется "длинный текст" https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%E2%80%94-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-memo-dffe5e34-953e-4451-a05e-fba5d9b564b5     Для sql аналогом будет LONGBLOB  (Может хранить не более 4 294 967 295 символов. )

Comment: А как добавлять значение для характеристик? Если они будут в виде текста

Comment: Так это текстовое поле... http://www.spravkaweb.ru/mysql/sql/vartype

Comment: Мы друг друга, видимо, не поняли) Мне надо добавлять характеристики для каждого товара. То есть, у всех телефонов разное количество памяти, к примеру, и нужно значение указывать при добавлении в БД. А если поле одно, то как добавить остальные характеристики? Или я вас не так понял?)

Comment: Вы не понимаете строение таблиц. Каждый товар - отдельная строка. Поля в строке - это другое. Поэтому получится, что содержание поля "характеристики" в строке id1234 совершенно различно с содержанием того же поля в строке с id9876

Comment: Я просто не пойму как потом эти характеристики заполнять с сайта

Comment: Через соответствующее поле в форме ввода данных, если делаете с интерфейсом, или путём импорта данных из файлов, например, csv

Comment: Просто в моём понимании для каждой характеристики нужно отдельное поле. То есть, отдельно "Оперативная память", "Диагональ экрана" и так далее. Чтобы потом без проблем выводить всё это

Comment: @Андрей Извините, что долго не отвечал... Если хотите сделать отдельными полями (ячейками в таблице) - делайте. Они так же будут содержаться в строке товара. Но я бы, все-таки оставил одно универсальное поле - так таблица будет работать быстрее

Comment: Я в итоге добавил поле description в таблице товаров и храню характеристики в формета JSON

Comment: @Андрей То же выход